# We are busy at the moment. Vs We are being busy at the moment

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, present-continuous

I am not sure about which option should I chose in the following context:

> It's Tom birthday today. We **are busy/are being busy** at the moment. Dad is doing some last-minute shopping. Mum is tidying the house.

Are both options correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We are busy at the moment" is the most natural one.

Comment: _Busy_ is an adjective describing how the family is today. _Being busy_ isn't an activity in itself.

Comment: Why? Is there a particular grammatical or semantic reason? Can you support your answer with references  that will help future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are good English, but only the first fits this context.

"*We are **busy** at the moment*" simply describes the fact of being busy.

"*We are **being busy** at the moment*" means being busy is intentional, and we might decide not to be busy later.

> We don't normally work this hard, but the company president is visiting this week so we're **being busy** to look good.